# CodeMirror - Catch Pick event for show hints

Tags: codemirror

I am trying to run a function when the "pick" object from CodeMirror's show hints pick function is triggered.

I have tried (among a lot of other options):

```
    CodeMirror.commands.pick = function (cm) {
        console.log(cm)
    }

    CodeMirror.on("pick", function (cm) { console.log(cm) } );

    var completion = cm.state.completionActive;
    console.log('handling the completion object:', completion);
    var pick = completion.pick;
    completion.pick = function (data, i) {
        var completion = data.list[i];
        console.log('picked', data, completion);
        pick.apply(this, arguments);
    }
```

In the documentation on codemirror it is described as:
"pick" (completion)
Fired when a completion is picked. Passed the completion value (string or object).

and I can see in the code for the show hints that this is triggered:

```
CodeMirror.signal(data, "pick", completion);
```

But how do I monitor that signal and react to it.

Comment: Did You get a solution for this? I am currently having the same issue